# Problem with inserting images with blogdown addin

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to insert an image inside a blogdown post. I'm using the [Hugo Academic Theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/academic/), with the repo on Github and deployed with Netlify.
When I write a new post and I use the addin that offer a GUI for images with the `blogdown:::insert_image_addin()` command. With the GUI I select my local image (like in the image below) and I have the markdown syntax for images with the linked picture.

[image: GUI for images].

However, there isn't the image in the linked location, so I have to move it manually. Is it normal? there are other quick methods to insert local images?

Comment: Sounds like a bug of this addin on Windows (I tested it on macOS and it worked fine). Please file an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues and `@lcolladotor` there. Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a bug. See 
https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/397 now

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug on blogdown and has now been fixed in current devel version.

You can do

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/blogdown")
```

to get the fix.

It we'll be included in next CRAN release Blogdown >= 0.15

See [PR 398](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/pull/398)